# pageXOffset and pageYOffset pixels calculation dependency and performance

Tags: javascript

I have two questions:

1) When I use pixels in pageYOffset or pageXOffset does it calculate the same for all devices? I'm just curious if some mobile devices may calculate it differently.

2) Are pageXOffset or pageYOffset consider as performance "heavy" if using them in conditions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(1) yes it will just give you the number of pixels you have scrolled, which is independent of device

(2) `pageXOffset/pageYOffset` are simply aliases of `scrollX` and `scrollY` which are not considered "heavy". though it depends what you personally mean by "heavy". They do not add any significant computation weight

Comment: I tried to use simple condition with pageYOffset to grayscale an image when it comes to 400pixels and this comes with a delay for stock android browser. Small delay however, but noticeable(around 3sec). It worked ok with chrome and firefox, tho.

Comment: 3 seconds is an extremely significant delay, there is no way that is coming from the pageYOffset call. it is more likely the grayscale process

Answer (score 0):

1. Yes. They are device independent.
2. Of course they are heavier than `x === 0`. But not as heavy as `document.createElement` indeed.